# C# code works when it hits breakpoint otherwise does not when i disable all breakpoint [Winforms]

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My code below runs perfectly when i try to debug applying breakpoint but when i disable breakpoints and run it again, it does not work perfectly. Here i am creating a non-stock item, now when it navigates to other page it does not show all the inserted rows.

I tried to make submit call async and put SaveNonStockItems() in await but it did not work

```
    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder quoteDetailIDs = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in grdQuoteDetail.Rows)
        {
            if (dataGridViewRow.Cells["colSelected"].Value != null &&
                dataGridViewRow.Cells["colSelected"].Value != DBNull.Value &&
                (bool)dataGridViewRow.Cells["colSelected"].Value)
            {
                quoteDetailIDs.Append(dataGridViewRow.Cells["colQuoteDetailID"].Value + ", ");
            }
        }
        StringBuilder quoteDetailIDsNonStock = new StringBuilder();
        if(SaveNonStockItems())
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in grdNonStocks.Rows)
                {
                    if (dataGridViewRow.Cells["colSelectedNonStock"].Value != null &&
                        dataGridViewRow.Cells["colSelectedNonStock"].Value != DBNull.Value &&
                        (bool)dataGridViewRow.Cells["colSelectedNonStock"].Value)
                    {
                        quoteDetailIDsNonStock.Append(dataGridViewRow.Cells["colQuoteDetailID2"].Value + ", ");
                    }
                }
                //  Remove trailing ', '
                quoteDetailIDs.Append(quoteDetailIDsNonStock.ToString());
                quoteDetailIDs.Remove(quoteDetailIDs.Length - 2, 2);

                Guid orderID = Guid.Empty;
                try
                {
                    BeginInit("Converting " + _quotesModule.QuoteTypeInfo.TypeName + "# " + _quotesModule.QuoteHeader[0].QuoteHeaderID + " To Order..."); 
 _quotesModule.ConvertToOrder(_quotesModule.QuoteHeader[0].QuoteHeaderID, _quotesModule.QuoteHeader[0].CustTreeNodeID,Guid.Empty,_quotesModule.QuoteHeader[0].SupplyChainNodeID, txtPONumber.Text, quoteDetailIDs.ToString(),
                    chkCopyItemNotes.Checked, rdoOpenOrder.Checked ? 1 : 2,
                    rdoOpenOrder.Checked ? 0 : ctrlVendor.SelectedSupplyChainNodeID,
                    ref orderID, SessionModule.Current.User.UnityUserID);  
                    EndInit();
                    Global.AppResume();
                    if (orderID != Guid.Empty)
                    {
                        Navigate.ReOpenOrder(orderID);
                    }
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ErrorDialog.DisplayModal(ex);
                    EndInit();
                    Global.AppResume();
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                }
        }

    private bool SaveNonStockItems()
    {
        if (grdNonStocks.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in grdNonStocks.Rows)
            {
                if (dataGridViewRow.Cells["colSelectedNonStock"].Value != null &&
                    dataGridViewRow.Cells["colSelectedNonStock"].Value != DBNull.Value &&
                    (bool)dataGridViewRow.Cells["colSelectedNonStock"].Value)
                {
                    string xml = CreateXml(dataGridViewRow);
                    if (xml != string.Empty)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int _skuID = ProductMaint.CreateNonStockingSku(xml, SessionModule.UserID); //Proc that inserts this
                            /* capture the item number for adding to the order (hack-ish) */
                            dataGridViewRow.Cells["colSkuID"].Value = _skuID;
                        }
                        catch (MercuryException mex)
                        {
                            /* non-stock creation failed */
                            ErrorDialog.DisplayModal("Non-stock creation failed.", mex.Message, true);
                            throw mex;

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ErrorDialog.DisplayModal("Failed to generate creation parameters.");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private string CreateXml(DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow)
    {
        System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        System.Xml.XmlNode root = doc.CreateElement("NonStockingSku");
        System.Xml.XmlNode sku = doc.CreateElement("Sku");
        System.Xml.XmlAttribute attr = null;


        doc.AppendChild(root);
        root.AppendChild(sku);
        attr = doc.CreateAttribute("ItemNumber");
        attr.Value = dataGridViewRow.Cells["colItemNumber2"].Value.ToString();
        sku.Attributes.Append(attr);

        attr = doc.CreateAttribute("Description");
        attr.Value = dataGridViewRow.Cells["colItemDescription2"].Value.ToString();
        sku.Attributes.Append(attr);

        attr = doc.CreateAttribute("ProductTypeID");
        attr.Value = dataGridViewRow.Cells["colType"].Value.ToString();
        sku.Attributes.Append(attr);

        attr = doc.CreateAttribute("ProductLineID");
        attr.Value = dataGridViewRow.Cells["colProductLine"].Value.ToString();
        sku.Attributes.Append(attr);

        attr = doc.CreateAttribute("ProductDepartmentID");
        attr.Value = dataGridViewRow.Cells["colDepartment"].Value.ToString();
        sku.Attributes.Append(attr);

        attr = doc.CreateAttribute("Landed");
        attr.Value = dataGridViewRow.Cells["colLanded"].Value.ToString();
        sku.Attributes.Append(attr);

        attr = doc.CreateAttribute("VendorSupplyChainNodeID");
        attr.Value = dataGridViewRow.Cells["colVendor"].Value.ToString();
        sku.Attributes.Append(attr);

        attr = doc.CreateAttribute("ListPrice");
        attr.Value = dataGridViewRow.Cells["colListPrice"].Value.ToString();
        sku.Attributes.Append(attr);

        attr = doc.CreateAttribute("Cost");
        attr.Value = dataGridViewRow.Cells["colCost"].Value.ToString();
        sku.Attributes.Append(attr);

        attr = doc.CreateAttribute("QuoteDetailID");
        attr.Value = dataGridViewRow.Cells["colQuoteDetailID2"].Value.ToString();
        sku.Attributes.Append(attr);

        attr = doc.CreateAttribute("Quantity");
        attr.Value = dataGridViewRow.Cells["colQuantity"].Value.ToString();
        sku.Attributes.Append(attr);



        return doc.OuterXml;

    }
}      
public static int CreateNonStockingSku(string parametersXml, int unityUserID)
    {
        Proc p = new Proc("NonStockingSku_i");
        p["@ParametersXml"] = parametersXml;
        p["@UnityUserID"] = unityUserID;
        p.Exec();

        int skuID;
        string message;

        if (p["@SkuID"] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            skuID = (int)p["@SkuID"];
            return skuID;
        }
        else
        {
            if (p["@Message"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                message = p["@Message"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Unspecified error.";
            }
            throw new MercuryException(message);
        }
    }
```

I just want to know the reson for it to behave like this. I have never encountered such problem in winforms, Is it because i am saving in loop or what i can't find problem, its a headache cuz only way is find problem is DEBUGGING however when i debug the code it works fine and results show fine.

Also, Data is getting stored in DB correctly it just does not load correctly at the form it navigates to.

Comment: Actually, the Row that gets inserted in DB from the SaveNonStockItems() method does not load in Grid at the form it navigates to. But it loads when i just debug or simply when code hits any breakpoint after i click submit.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Your DB is not in-process (i.e. it is running as a separate process on your or another machine). Creating a non-stock item will take some time, but your program does not wait until the non-stock items have been created and go forward fetching the information from the DB which lacks some of the non-stock items that still in the process of being created. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Now, adding breakpoints makes your program pause at those breakpoints, essentially delaying program execution long enough (that is the time until you tell the debugger to proceed execution) for the backend to complete creation/persisting of the non-stock items. But as i said, this is just pure speculation, a (simple) scenario that even if it does not explain your particular circumstances can at least illustrate how having breakpoints being hit can seemingly alter the flow of data or behavior of a program...

Comment: Yes, i agree with you,sql server db is hosted at a server, even i think the same. Is there any efficient workaround that I can use.

Comment: I can't help you. I don't even know what exactly is going on in your program and with your DB at all. A possible solution (or workaround) would depend on knowing this, and due to my complete and utter lack of the particular circumstances that cause your problem i am unable to make meaningful suggestions. With regard to your probem i could only be like a guy suggesting to slap a flaky TV a few times on its side in an attempt to get the picture back on screen... ;-)

Comment: what's the code behind CreateNonStockingSku?

Comment: You mentioned trying "async". Is any method you are using returning a `Task` that you now just ignore instead of `await` or even returning `void`? When you use async, everything from the database call up to the initiating (click) handler must be async and you must await everything.

Comment: I have added code behind CreateNonStockingSku @Robert.